# How to access this in my view

Tags: php, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

I am new with this laravel , I am using resource.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Cars;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class BookController extends Controller
{
       public function show($id)
    {
        $car = Cars::where('car_id',$id);
        return view('book.view',compact('car'));
    }
}
```

Here is my route.php

```
  Route::resource('book','BookController');
```

Here is my view.blade.php

```
     {{ $car->car_id }}
```

but it gives me error 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$car_id

How can I display the car_id ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to fetch single record then do

```
$car = Cars::where('car_id', $id)->first();
return view('view.name', compact('car'))
```

and then access it in view like this :

```
{{$car->car_id}}
```

if you want to fetch many records do like this :

```
$cars = Cars::where('something', '=','otherthing')->get();
return view('view.name', compact('cars'));
```

and access it in view like this:

```
@foreach($cars as $car)
    {{$car->car_id}}
@endforeach
```

You should follow naming conventions **Never make your model name plural**

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$car = Cars::where('car_id','=',$id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get specific columns of all data in cars table using this:

```
$car=Cars::where('car_id',$id)->get(['car_id','car_name']);
```